# Android--SQL Server Connectivity error

Tags: android, sql-server, wcf

I'm new to the android but now days done much more coding in Android. Now I have a doubt. I created android database application using Android and SQL Lte. But SQL Lite is client site database. But now my requirement is,I want a database like SQL Server,so that I connect my application to SQL Server. So suppose,consider and example,I know about WCF. I create a WCF service which have a function just like:
I hosted WCF on IIS because android does not response localhost,so i hosted WCF on IIS

```
Public string check(string username,string password)

{

 SQLConnection con=new SQLConnection("Data Source=.;Database=test;Integrated Security=true");

 SQLDataAdapeter ad=new SQLDataAdapter("select * from table where usrename='"+username+"'and password='"+password+"'");

 Dataset ds=new Dataset();

 ad.fill(ds,"table");

if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count>0)
 {
  return "true";
 }
else
{
 return "false";
}

}
```

I hosted WCF in my local host so that I can use this service in My Android Application coding.

just like:

```
HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet("http://192.168.1.111:8083/Service1.svc/checkLogin?username="+UserName+"&password="+Password);

        //Get the response
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        InputStream stream=httpEntity.getContent();
```

However here I'm not getting any httpEntity though the code is correct.
I take this entity and want to convert it into string by using function like:

```
public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is)
{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

however,it does not return any string value,the debugger goes on catch point.
So what can I do so that i'll get result in string format from my WCF?

Answer (score 0):

Based on above code, I am not sure how do you put mobile client app, WCF and SQL Server in perspective. The basic design is that WCF service will internally talk to SQL Azure and collect data for your. You mobile client will just connect to WCF service at exposed method and the method will pass the data to mobile client. I do not see that architecture in above description or code snippet.

I would suggest you to use oData WCF Data Services to connect any mobile application to SQL Server. OData services are fast and easy way to connect on-premise SQL Server or Cloud based RDBMS i.e. SQL Azure.

This [article](http://anindita9.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/consuming-sql-serversql-azure-data-in-windows-phone-7-1-android-through-odata-wcf-data-services-entity-frameworks/) explains how to do it step by step so I would suggest trying it and if you met any problem, post to SO and we sure will help you:

Most of the Android developers actually prefer WCF using JSON to connect from Android to SQL Server/Azure so you sure can take a look as well [here](http://guruparan.blog.com/2012/03/30/connecting-android-to-sql-server-via-wcf-using-json-part-1/).

Comment: Ok I will try your links. But my scenario is I want to connect my android application to SQL Server. As I'm .Net developer,I know about WCF and Web Service Concepts well. And I already heard that if we want to connect our Android application to SQL Server,we must use web service or WCF. So Ihave created WCF Service from .Net i.e from Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: You are absolutely right and I agree to use WCF, so  I would suggest using oData WCF Services as to write a sample app, it took about 30 minutes for me with it.